# How do you apply a script or forum button to an image?

Tags: html, image, forms, button, passwords

I would like the "download" button link on http://00100101.com/dlc (tumblr) to be the image(s) above it instead. IOW the image as the button link; the current button link is encrypted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the onclick from the buttons to the respective images. I hope those don't need to be too secure. Using javascript for password protection isn't very secure since users simply need to inspect the page source to find the password in the script.

HTML:

```
<img src="http://36.media.tumblr.com/5542f9a116668a81a87d6aa21ce59728/tumblr_inline_nw50waYzLZ1ryqqko_500.jpg" onclick="passWord()">

<img src="http://40.media.tumblr.com/934f9533ca6c389ad5e6b08901be1e27/tumblr_inline_nv1mmbjKQm1ryqqko_500.jpg" onclick="passWord1()">
```

Comment: thanks...nah nothing too secret, just needed something basic

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
<button type="submit">
       <img src="/path/to/image" alt="Submit">
</button>
```